# Perfect Binary Tree with correct data

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I am having a problem trying to fill the data a perfect binary tree with a known number of nodes with the correct data. Basically, I have an implementation that creates this:

```
     7
  5     6
 1 2   3 4
```

However, I am looking to create a tree like this:

```
     7
  3     6
 1 2   4 5
```

My current implementation for inserting the nodes of a tree is as follows.

```
def _add_node(self, val, ref = None):
    # reference to root of tree
    ref = self.root if ref is None else ref

    if ref.right is None:
        ref.right = Node(val, ref)
        return
    elif ref.left is None:
        ref.left = Node(val, ref)
        return
    else:
        parent = (val - 1) / 2
        if parent % 2 == 0:
            self._add_node(val, ref.left) 
        else:
            self._add_node(val, ref.right)
```

Given `x` nodes I create a tree using `range(x)` and  calling `add_node(i)` for each iteration. This works fine except its order is incorrect.

For the life of me I cannot figure out an easy way to set the values to represent the bottom layout rather than the top. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be an issue with the order that you are entering data in. How are you passing in the data?

Also think about your implementation. You check to see whether the right child is empty and if it is you place the node there. However, if it isn't you move on to the left node. This is where the issue is happening.

Assuming you are passing in the data in reverse chronological order you start with 7 at the root. Then you move to 6 which you place in the right node. Then move on to 5; you check to see whether the right node is empty, which is isn't because it is filled with 6, so you move on to check if the left node is empty and find that it is. So you place 5 there.

Do you see the issue?

You need to figure out a way to get around this issue, but hopefully this was good in helping you debug.

Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry about that. Back when I did answer this I didn't have commenting abilities.